# How to modify image when source contains a certain letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify an image only if the source contains certain letters. For example, trying to find out if the image source contains "-large":

Example source:

Here's what I have:

```
if($('img.someclass').indexOf('-large') === -1){
```

This seems to somewhat work, but once it triggers, it breaks other elements in the page, and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('img.someclass').indexOf('-large')')
```

Any better way of going about this?

Comment: Don't you need to get the `src` value? E.g. `$('img.someclass').attr('src').indexOf('-large')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
if($('img.someclass').attr('src').indexOf('-large') !== -1){}
```

BTW, you can just select it by:

```
$('img.someclass[src*="-large"]')
```

Comment: `.indexOf()` returns *-1* if the value is not found. Your if statement should be `.indexOf('-large') > -1` (contains) or `.indexOf('-large') === -1` (does not have)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get the source of the image for your check.

Try this:

```
if($('img.someclass')[0].src.indexOf('-large') >= 0){
```

or

```
if($('img.someclass').attr('src').indexOf('-large') >= 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
if($('img.someclass[src*="-large"]').length > 0){
  /*Your Code Here*/   
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K585b/1/)